# DynamoDB Streams exception

Tags: java, amazon-dynamodb

I am trying to implement the Dynamodb Streams Java example from AWS.  I get the following 2 errors repeated several times and then the program completes as expected.  Any ideas what the cause is?

```
[error] c.a.s.k.c.l.w.ShardSyncTask - Caught exception while sync'ing Kinesis shards and leases
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBStreams; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnknownOperationException; Request ID: VEPKVGT3GN8BSBP3A74LOEVIPVVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.java:638) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.describeStream(AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.java:363) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.20.jar:na]
[error] c.a.s.d.s.m.AmazonServiceExceptionTransformer - Could not transform a DynamoDB AmazonServiceException to a compatible Kinesis exception
com.amazonaws.AmazonServiceException: null (Service: AmazonDynamoDBStreams; Status Code: 400; Error Code: UnknownOperationException; Request ID: JLVS3D8Q363LGGI60O42LDULBFVV4KQNSO5AEMVJF66Q9ASUAAJG)
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.handleErrorResponse(AmazonHttpClient.java:1182) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeOneRequest(AmazonHttpClient.java:770) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.executeHelper(AmazonHttpClient.java:489) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.http.AmazonHttpClient.execute(AmazonHttpClient.java:310) ~[aws-java-sdk-core-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.invoke(AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.java:638) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.20.jar:na]
    at com.amazonaws.services.dynamodbv2.AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.describeStream(AmazonDynamoDBStreamsClient.java:363) ~[aws-java-sdk-dynamodb-1.10.20.jar:na]
```

Comment: so `describeStream` results in an `UnknownOperationException`? Are you using outdated versions of the aws sdk maybe? Edit: nope, 1.10.20 is the most recent.

Answer (score 3):

We had the same problem, and it turned out we where missing the region in our settings, explicitly setting the region made it work.

For dynamodb-local you don't need a region though, so using that it will work without the region, and then when you deploy it in AWS you will get the above error.

Answer (score 0):

The answer provided by @mikeal-sundberg didn't work for me, I eventually figured it was down to a difference between provided endpoints in AWS vs Dynamo local.

With Dynamo local you can use the same endpoint for the standard Dynamo client as well as the `AmazonDynamoDBStreams` client.  When deployed, the `AmazonDynamoDBStreams` client needs a streams specific endpoint such as `https://streams.dynamodb.eu-west-1.amazonaws.com`.